# How can I get channel information inside Bot composer

Tags: bot-framework-composer

I am building a bot using the Bot composer that is registered across channels. I want to capture and log the channel information, such as the channel source (Telegram, Line). Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see it in `turn.activity.channelId`

Comment: No problem, you can mark the answer as correct so it can help others

Answer (score 0):

To view complete Json payload use `${turn.Activity}` and for the channel source you can use `${turn.Activity.channelId}`.